# How to open video url in external player in react-native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I need to open links like this

```
http://somedomen.com/someplaylist.m3u8
```

in external videoplayer.
I can't find the specific url scheme for this to Linking (so

```
Linking.openURL('video:http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4');
```

not works

```
Linking.openURL('intent://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;scheme=http;type=video/mp4;end');
```

not works too
)

I trying the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-intent with some modifications of mine.

It works, but when the external player opens and I press the BACK button - application closes without errors. I think that the new intent creates in the same activity.

So my question:
Is there any way to open video links with external player (like share works but user need to select from video players installed on the system to open shared link with the selected one).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work with this module http://npmjs.com/package/react-native-intent-launcher